# Dynamic programming assembly line scheduling

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am reading about Dynamic programming in Cormen etc book on algorithms. following is text from book

Suppose we have motor car factory with two assesmly lines called as line 1 and line 2. We have to determine fastest time to get chassis all the way.

Ultimate goal is to determine the fastest time to get a chassis all the way through the factory, which we denote by Fn. The chasssis has to get all the way through station "n" on either line 1 or line 2 and then to factory exit. Since the faster of these ways is the fastest way through the entire factory, we have

```
Fn = min(f1[n] + x1, f2[n]+x2) ---------------- Eq1

Above x1 and x2 final additional time for comming out from line 1 and line 2
```

I have following recurrence equations. Consider following are Eq2.

```
f1[j]  = e1 + a1,1                                    if j = 1
             min(f1[j-1] + a1,j, f2[j-1] + t2,j-1 + a1,j  if j >= 2

f2[j]  = e2 + a2,1                                    if j = 1
             min(f2[j-1] + a2,j, f1[j-1] + t1,j-1 + a2,j  if j >= 2
```

Let Ri(j) be the number of references made to fi[j] in a recursive algorithm.

From equation R1(n) = R2(n) = 1

From equation 2 above we have

```
R1(j) = R2(j) = R1(j+1) + R2(j+1)  for j = 1, 2, ...n-1
```

My question is how author came with R(n) =1 because usally we have base case as 0 rather than n, here then how we will write recursive functions in code
for example C code?

Another question is how author came up with R1(j) and R2(j)?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you solve the problem in a recursive way, what would you do?
You'd start calculating F(n). F(n) would recursively call f1(n-1) and f2(n-1) until getting to the leaves (f1(0), f2(0)), right?

So, that's the reason the number of references to F(n) in the recursive solution is 1, because you'd need to compute f1(n) and f2(n) only once. This is not true to f1(n-1), which is referenced when you compute f1(n) and when you compute f2(n).

Now, how did he come up with R1(j) = R2(j) = R1(j+1) + R2(j+1)?
well, computing it in a recursive way, every time you need f1(i), you have to compute f1(j), f2(j), for every j in the interval [0, i) -- AKA for every j smaller than i.
In other words, the value of f1,2(i) depends on the value of f1,2(0..i-1), so every time you compute a f_(i), you're computing EVERY f1,2(1..i-1) - (because it depends on their value).

For this reason, the number of times you compute f_(i) depends on how many f1,2 there are "above him".

Hope that's clear.

Comment: in above in last paragraph third line is the the value of f1,2(i) depends on the value of f1,2(0..j) i.e., instead of i it should be j? am i right?

Comment: No, but it should be f1,2(1...i-1) - (Editing the answer)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer: for either f1(i) or f2(i), the value of such f(i) depends on the value of f1(0), f1(1), f1(2), ..., f1(i-1), f2(0), f2(1), f2(2), ... f2(i-1).

Comment: This is just another way to express f_(i) depends on f1(j), f2(j), for every j in the interval [0, i) -- (AKA for every j smaller than i)